# How to split the data from csv and store in a variable for later use in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I tried my best but no luck. Experts please help

I'm trying to get the vin numbers from csv file and using BeanShellPreProcessor to split

Here is my code

"vin" is the datasheetname and storing in variable t. I can successfully print the value of t in the Jmeter console.

Now I took the value that I got in t, and want to get the string starting from 10th Index to 17th Index and want to put that splitted string into a variable that I can use in my SOAP Request.

But when I use in the SOAP Request like this     ${output}, it is getting as is instead of the value

what am I doing wrong?

String t = vars.get("vin");
System.out.println(timer);

string varm = t.substring(10, 17);
vars.put("output", varm.toString());

Comment: I fixed it my self. PLease ignore. Thanks

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, to help anyone else who may run into the same issue.

Comment: Here is the solution   
vars.put("output", t.substring(10, 17));

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in second line:

> System.out.println(timer)

should be:

> System.out.println(t)

And

> string

should be:

> String

By the way you should use Groovy within JSR223 rather than beanshell